# Calculate tax return

Tags: java, design-patterns

Please consider this code for a `TaxReturnCalculator` (and ignore both the suboptimal use of `float` instead of `BigDecimal` and non-existing parameter validation):

```
public class TaxReturnCalculator {
    
    private static final float FIFTY_PERCENT = 0.5f;
    private static final float THIRTY_PERCENT = 0.3f;
    private static final float MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_TAX_RETURN = 1000f;
    
    public static float calculateTaxReturn(float income)
    {
        float basicTaxReturn = calculateBasicTaxReturn(income);
        
        float taxReturnAddition = calculateTaxReturnAddition(basicTaxReturn);
        
        float taxReturn = basicTaxReturn + taxReturnAddition;
        
        float taxReturnLimited = calculateTaxReturnLimited(taxReturn);
        
        return taxReturnLimited;
    }

    private static float calculateBasicTaxReturn(float income)
    {
        return income * FIFTY_PERCENT; // More complex calculation here
    }

    private static float calculateTaxReturnAddition(float basicTaxReturn) 
    {       
        return basicTaxReturn * THIRTY_PERCENT;  // More complex calculation here
    }
    
    private static float calculateTaxReturnLimited(float taxReturn)
    {
        float taxReturnLimited;
        
        if(taxReturn > MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_TAX_RETURN)
        {
            taxReturnLimited = MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_TAX_RETURN;
        }
        else
        {
            taxReturnLimited = taxReturn;
        }
        
        return taxReturnLimited;
    }
}
```

I designed the `calculateTaxReturn(float income)` method to follow the

> One Level of Abstractoin per Function

practice recommended in *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: The three functions inside this method are on the same level of abstraction.

However, what doesn't seem well designed to me is that `calculateTaxReturnLimited(taxReturn)` is always called and thus always produces a `taxReturnLimited` -- even if the tax return is not to be limited (because it's smaller than the maximum amount)! Isn't this confusing?

Of course I could avoid this by not having a `calculateTaxReturnLimited` function at all and put it's code directly inside of the `calculateTaxReturn`, but that would vialote the *One Level of Abstractoin per Function* principle.

Renaming the function to something like *limitTaxReturnIfNecessary* doesn't seem good to me either, having multiple *...IfNecessary* functions seems like a clutter and code smell to me.

Is this a trade-off? How can it be resolved best to follow best practices?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I think you are misunderstanding/mis-using the practice you reference. Specifically, deciding if you calculate whether a limited tax return is required is not a responsibility of actually doing the calculation. Additionally, I would argue that the overall abstraction is "calculation of the tax return", and thus internal helper functions are not required here, especially given their (current) simplicity

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The requirements use the same structure/terms (`basic`, `addition`, `limited`), that's one reason why I structured the function like this, too. Thanks for the first part of your comment, too. However, I don't want to focus on that. Please assume that the "limited" function makes sense in the "calculation" context and that that function is complex enough that it makes sense to introduce internal helper functions. My question: How do you deal with helper functions which have "if's" inside (like in the example above) which makes it hard to name them in a meaningful way?

Comment: In that case, I lean towards considering this off topic, because it is hypothetical/stub code

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write `...ifNecessary` if you just describe the property you want to have in the return value, and then you just know that after calling it, it has that property. You want the return amount to be `clamp`ed so it is less than or equal to the maximum amount. It doesn't matter that it might not change it, but it DOES matter to the business logic that it has been applied (i.e. checked). The actual name isn't that important in this case because I think I'd drop it anyway, as per below.

First, I just rewrote your code to use a member variable instead of being static, and without all the intermediate variables:

```java
public class TaxReturn {

    private static final float MAXIMUM_RETURN_AMOUNT= 1000f;

    private final float income;

    public TaxReturn(float income) {
        this.income = income;
    }

    public float returnAmount() {
        return clampReturnAmount(base() + addition());
    }

    private float base() {
        return income * 0.5f; // More complex calculation here
    }

    private float addition() {
        return base() * 0.3f; // More complex calculation here
    }

    private static float clampReturnAmount(float returnAmount) {
        return returnAmount > MAXIMUM_RETURN_AMOUNT ? MAXIMUM_RETURN_AMOUNT
                : returnAmount;
    }

}
```

But this `clampReturnAmount` function is just `Math.min` by a different name. Using `Math.min` to enforce a limit is common enough to be well understood why we're calling it, especially if we're naming the second argument something like argument `MAXIMUM_RETURN_AMOUNT`. So just:

```java
public class TaxReturn {

    private static final float MAXIMUM_RETURN_AMOUNT = 1000f;

    private final float income;

    public TaxReturn(float income) {
        this.income = income;
    }

    public float returnAmount() {
        return Math.min(base() + addition(), MAXIMUM_RETURN_AMOUNT);
    }

    private float base() {
        return income * 0.5f; // More complex calculation here
    }

    private float addition() {
        return base() * 0.3f; // More complex calculation here
    }

}
```